# Как добавить запись в реестр и проверить ее существование на python?

Tags: python, winapi, реестр, ctypes

Я написал код который добавляет программу в автозагрузку,но только в HKEY_LOCAL_USER.Мне бы хотелось добавить для всех пользователей и ещё как праверить существование данной записи.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос текущей код (кнопка `править`) -- так желающим помочь будет проще отталкиваться

Comment: А модуль https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/winreg.html чем не угодил? Правда, всегда напоминаю, что это low-level и нужно поаккуратнее.